# Convert curl command (terminal mac) to PHP code

Tags: php, macos, curl, terminal

how can I convert:

```
curl -s \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-u api:12345 \
-X GET \
'http://sampleurl.com/api/orders.json?limit=250&offset=0'
```

into a proper PHP command?

Answer (score 0):

I think your wording on "PHP command" is a bit fuzzy.. a curl command like this cannot be expressed in 1 single PHP line, it needs to be a script (meaning several lines)..

I recommend using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), a free Chrome extension/app that is a fantastic REST client.

And the best part is, it allows you to export your HTTP requests in several formats, also as PHP snippets.

And no, I'm not involved with the Postman development ;-)

[image: postman export]